# Rapid update of bounding box when one of a thousand items moves?

Tags: data-structures, spatial-index

I have thousands of objects represented by axis-aligned bounding boxes. I can calculate the smallest axis-aligned bounding box containing all of the items easily, but it's a rather expensive operation. I'd like to have a structure where I can insert/update/delete items in at most logarithmic time, and then get the current bounding box containing all items in constant time.

What data structure is a good fit for this problem?

Comment: Out of curiousity, how did you end up solving the problem?

Comment: Two sorted lists, one for each axis. Insert/delete is in log time, using binary search. Min/max are constant time by looking at head/tail of the list.

Comment: How do you support updates?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simpler idea: 4 binary trees.

So 4 power-of-two-sized arrays. The root will be in element 1, and the bounding boxes of the objects are the leaves (in the last half of the array). The parent of two nodes will hold the `min` (or `max`) of its two children. Unused leaves should hold `int.MinValue` or `int.MaxValue` (for `max` and `min` tree respectively). Updating is pretty simple in O(log n), see below.

You'd have

1. a tree with `min` for the `left` coordinate
2. a tree with `max` for the `right` coordinate
3. a tree with `min` for the `top` coordinate
4. a tree with `max` for the `bottom` coordinate

The total bounding box is described by the roots, available in O(1).

Update procedure is something like this: (untested)

```
update(array, item, newvalue)
    index = (array.length >> 1) + item  // index of leaf
    array[index] = newvalue;
    while (index > 1)
        parent = index >> 1
        sibling = index ^ 1
        array[parent] = min(array[index], array[sibling])
        index = parent
```

There is a possibility for early exit, if the update of the parent doesn't change it.

This generalizes to trees with a higher degree, making them shallower at the expense of taking a `min` or `max` over more than 2 items. In my experience, that can be worth it for larger trees, but only up to a point, increasing the degree quickly runs into diminishing returns. You could try 4 and 8 (power-of-two degrees are best, it avoids complicating the math).

Answer (score 0):

There are a class of data structures called *kinetic data structures* that support efficient multidimensional queries under the assumption that the underlying elements are moving. I'm not much of an expert on them, but [this set of lecture slides](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~pankaj/publications/slides/kinetic-range.pdf) seems like a great starting point. It looks like the STAR-tree might be a good data structure to look at; it looks like it's a kinetic version of an R-tree.

Hope this helps!